# Method to compare two pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) using NIST?

Tags: p-value, random-generation

I have to create two pseudorandom number generators and test which one produces a more random output using NIST. Could someone suggest a setup whereby I can confirm or deny that one pseudorandom number generator is better than the other using NIST? If NIST is not appropriate for comparing the two PRNGs, could someone possibly suggest a better testing method?

An output generated by the various tests on NIST is p-values. Could I use the combined p-value from tests on many sequences from each PRNG to see which is better?

Comment: The point to offering an entire suite of tests is that "better" is not usually well-defined: one PRNG might fail some of the tests and another PRNG might fail other tests.  You need to decide which failures matter in your intended application(s).  Thus, combining p-values (apart from the many problems others will surely point out with that approach) would be irrelevant.  Likewise, given the broad general context you offer, it would be difficult to provide objective support for recommending a "better" testing method.  Could you therefore explain *why* you need to create PRNGs?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, but you might want to look at L'Ecuyer and Simard's article on their TestU01 suite (a sort of competitor to NIST,  without NIST's partial focus on cryptography).  There are crude comparisons between PRNGs by numbers of test failures, or by which tests are failed.  I don't think it makes sense to try to combine tests into a single number, though, because component tests look at different properties of the generated sequences.  That's true for NIST, too.  I also highly recommend the material on testing in chapter 3 of Knuth's _The Art of Computer Programming_.